# How to sum all the numbers in a text file?

Tags: python, file

I have to calculate the sum of any numbers in the file and print the sum.

A number is defined as any string beginning with a digit 0 through 9 followed by any number of digits 0 through 9.

Alphanumeric strings (strings including both numbers and letters) are not to be included in the summation.

This is the content of the file:

```
a b cddde ff 1
5
hH five lll 0
l 10
99 abcd7
9kk
0
```

So the answer would be 115 in this case.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I'm supposed to find the sum of what is listed in bold italics but i don't know how

Comment: Always tag questions with the language used, and include errors

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@MarkyPython: Please don't add `Python:` before the title, because this question is tagged [tag:Python], so it's not needed and should be removed.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
def function():

    infile = open("test.txt", 'r')
    content = infile.read()       
    infile.close()
    wordList = content.split()

    total = 0

    for i in wordList:
        if i.isnumeric():
            total += int(i)
    return total
```

In this solution, I named the file test.txt. The idea is you loop through wordList which is a list containing every item spliced in test.txt (try printing wordList before the loop to see for yourself). We then try to cast each item as a int (this assumes no decimals will be in the file, if so you can include a float cast). We then catch ValueError which gets raised when casting i.e 'a' as an int.

Comment: Why go to all that trouble when python has the `isnumeric()` function builtin?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that use RegEx:

```
import re

with open('file') as f:
    print(sum(int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', f.read())))
```

In this case:

- `\b+` match all the numbers, and `\b` checks if there a letter after (or before) the number so we can ignore `abcd7` or `9kk`.
- [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) try to find all the numbers in the file use the RegEx `\b\d+\b` and returns a list.
- A *list compression*, `int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b')`, convert all the elements in the list which returned by `re.findall()` to `int` object.
- [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function sums the elements of a list, and returns the result.

[**Online RegEx demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eB3uU4/1)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is use `item.isnumeric()`.  If the item made up of only numbers and not letters or other characters it will return true.

So you check the all the items in `wordList` and if the item `isnumeric()` you add the item to `total`.

```
infile = open(filename.txt, 'r')
content = infile.read()       
infile.close()

wordList = content.split()    
total = 0

for item in wordList:
    if item.isnumeric():
        total += int(item)
```